# join large tables - transactional log full due to active transaction

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two large tables with 60 million, resp. 10 million records. I want to join both tables together however the process runs for 3 hours then comes back with the error message:

> the transaction log for database is full due to 'active_transaction'

- The autogrowth is unlimited and I have set the DB recovery to simple
- The size of the log drive is 50 GB

I am using `SQL server 2008 r2`.

The `SQL` query I am using is:

```
Select * into betdaq.[dbo].temp3  from 
 (Select XXXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX    
 from XXX.[dbo].temp1 inner join XXX.[dbo].temp2
 on temp1.Date = temp2.[Date] and temp1.cloth = temp2.Cloth nd temp1.Time = temp1.Time) a
```

Comment: have you evaluated "count x the size of the returned row" ?

Answer (score 2):

A single command is a transaction and the transaction does not commit until the end.
So you are filling up the transaction log.

You are going to need to loop and insert like 100,000 rows at a time

Start with this just to test the first 100,000
Then will need to add loop with a cursor

```
create table betdaq.[dbo].temp3  ...
insert into betdaq.[dbo].temp3  (a,b,c,d,e)
Select top 100000 with ties XXXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX    
  from XXX.[dbo].temp1 
  join XXX.[dbo].temp2
    on temp1.Date = temp2.[Date] 
   and temp1.Time = temp1.Time
   and temp1.cloth = temp2.Cloth 
 order by temp1.Date, temp1.Time
```

And why? That is a LOT of data.  Could you use a View or a CTE?
If those join columns are indexed a View will be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction log can be full even though database is in simple recovery model,even though select into is a minimally logged operation,log can become full due to other transactiosn running in parallel as well.

I would use below queries to check tlog space usage by transactions while the query is runnnig

```
select * from sys.dm_db_log_space_usage

select * from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions
select * from sys.dm_tran_active_transactions
select * from sys.dm_tran_current_transaction
```

further below query can be used to check sql text also

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Transaction-Log-Usage-By-e62ba57d